# If I'm using a CDN should I host my images (the originals) at high resolution and no compression?

Tags: wordpress, cdn, cloudflare

I'm about to start testing W3 Total Cache plugin for WordPress with Cloudflare for CDN.

Is there any downside (other than file size/space on server) to hosting the original images that the CDN uses to populate its delivery network at a high resolution with no or little compression? I think there's a few upsides to doing it as long as there aren't any downsides or the downsides are negligible.

I serve a number of original images as well as hosting a stream of images that are updated every 15 minutes that I am licensed to display on my site. My goal is to always serve the fastest, quality image available for their screensize/bandwidth. Would a best practice be to host or link to the originals at the max resolution they'll be displayed at on my site and then let the CDN handle all the sizes below?

Any experience or advice?

Comment: I don't think this is on topic here as it seems to Wordpress specific (try wordpress.stackexchange.com).  AFAIK thought W3 total cache does not resize images, it only provides caching of images.  https://wordpress.org/support/topic/suggest-image-compression-plugin-that-works-with-w3-total-cache/ appears to be on point here.